# What is the jQuery alternative to not(':not( selector )')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the jQuery **alternative** to not(':not( selector )')?

Basically lets say this:

```
var buttons = $('a.buttons');
```

I am looking for a particular button with the href as '#measurement' and need to add a class to it. The only way I know how to do this is with not(':not( selector )').

```
buttons.not(':not([href="#measurement"])').addClass('selected');
```

There has got to be a better way.

```
.is() // returns boolean
.has() // looks for items inside each element
```

Any thing out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want `filter`:

```
$elements.filter(selector)
```

so if you already have

```
var $buttons = $('a.buttons');
```

you can get the right one by

```
var $theButtonIWant = $buttons.filter('[href*="#measurement"]');
```

Comment: No worries. jQuery API is not exactly small. :p

Comment: Just discovered you can throw in a function, which combined with Regex can be super powerful.

`buttons.filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('href').match(/#measurement/); })`

This is definitely overkill in my example but can be extremely useful.

Answer (score 4):

The 2 `not`s cancel out, and you get

```
$('a.buttons[href="#measurement"]').addClass('selected');
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

EDIT: If you already have a collection, use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
var buttons = $('a.buttons');
buttons.filter('[href="#measurement"]').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: @iambriansreed: How about now? :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
var button = $('a.buttons[href*="#measurement"]').addClass('selected');
```

The [ ] block lets you specify an attribute. The *= operator in it specifies that the attribute contains the quoted text.

Comment: Of course as Rocket mentioned above, if your href attribute is exactly set to #measurement then you can simply omit the * in my example.

Comment: "I am looking for a particular button with the href as '#measurement' and need to add a class to it. The only way I know how to do this is with not(':not( selector )')." That's exactly what we gave you. You did list your original selector of all the elements, but you didn't state that you wanted to filter that selection down. Stack is usually full of people who code how they know, not how they should :P so we all tend to interpret code based on the desired goal, not the sample given ;) I'm glad you got what you needed though :)

Comment: You didn't read the question in it's entirety. Which is why your answer was incorrect and wasn't accepted. My question was good enough for @Amadan to answer correctly.